# Extract root level element from file path in Java

Tags: java

I want to extract the very first part from the file path, lets say

```
dev/sda/asset/
dev/sda/asset/media/
dev/sda/asset/media/trancodedvideo/
```

I want to fetch the very first part from all the above paths i,e `dev`

I have snippet which only works for fixed set of path i,e 3 `dev/sda/asset/`

```
    public static String getRootKey(String key) {
        File f = new File(key);
        Path p = f.toPath();
        int pathElements = p.getNameCount();
        String rootKey = p.getName(pathElements - 3).toString(); // returns dev
        return rootKey;
    }
```

I am looking for more robust solution more preferably in java 8+, because the above approach will be break if the there are hierarchy more than 3.

Please suggest

Comment: ***substring*** on the ***index of*** the first '/' char

Comment: [Path#getRoot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getRoot())

Comment: Root is giving me an exception, it seems it is implemented for linux based system, it tried to find `/`.

Comment: your substring approach looks fine for me because `indexOf` every time give me the first occurrence so doesn't matter how many number of hierarchy is ther, it always give me the root part, thanks